# Magento 2.1.8 issue Undefined variable: imageBlockBuilder

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.8

I got following error in Magento 2.1.8 in my custom theme e.g. mytheme.

> Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable:
>   imageBlockBuilder in
>   /home/public_html/app/design/frontend/Company/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml
>   on line 220

Answer (score 6):

As **imageBlockBuilder** is no longer used in Magento 2.1.8 
To fix above error do following:

Replace:

```
$productImage = $imageBlockBuilder->buildBlock($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
```

with

```
$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea);
```

Here **$imageDisplayArea** may be different variable in your case, change it as per your need.